# How to pass tapStorageOut to clientInfo in MTAudioProcessingTapInitCallback

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, avplayer

Im trying to convert to Swift [this](https://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/) tutorial that explains how to use `MTAudioProcessingTap`. In the `MTAudioProcessingTapInitCallback` it is passing the clientInfo which is a `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>` to the tapStorageOut which is a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`

like this in Objc:

```
void init(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void **tapStorageOut)
{
    NSLog(@"Initialising the Audio Tap Processor");
    *tapStorageOut = clientInfo;
}
```

Now the question is.. how I do that in Swift ?

```
let tapInit: MTAudioProcessingTapInitCallback = {
        (tap, clientInfo, tapStorageOut) in

        print("init \(tap, clientInfo, tapStorageOut)\n")

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tapStorageOut.pointee = clientInfo
```

p.s not a swift thing, but I’ve never understood why taps allow tapStorage and clientInfo to differ.

Comment: oh wow.. THank you man. This at least allows me to compile. 
Now im working in converting the the bufferListInOut to a CMSampleBuffer. :-s